# Invalid Cast Exception for System.Windows.Controls.Canvas to System.Windows.Controls.TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am creating textboxes on canvas in run time, that's why I can't use event `KeyDown` on the textbox that was pressed.

Here is my code:

```
private void canvas1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    int line = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)sender).Name.Substring(4, 1));
    //here pop up exception

    int column = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)sender).Name.Substring(3, 1));
}
```

The exception is:

> "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Canvas' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox'."

Comment: Exception is quite clear: `sender` (i.e. object that fired `KeyDown` event) is `System.Windows.Controls.Canvas` but you cast it to `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox`.

Comment: `sender` is of type `System.Windows.Controls.Canvas` but you're trying to cast to `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox`. Change the cast to `((Canvas)sender)...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sender` is the canvas object not the textbox. You're trying to cast the canvas as a textbox which isn't possible, hence the exception. Why not attach a common event handler to the textbox at runtime?

```
myTextBox.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(TextBox_KeyDown);

private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //the sender will be a TextBox here, but perform a check to avoid null exception
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    if(tb != null)
    {
       //your textbox code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to cast a canvas as a textbox hence the exception. As evident from your code, the keydown event is associated with the canvas and not the text box and the sender object will always be a canvas in this case.

You need to attach a keydown event to the text box at runtime if the text box is created at runtime.

```
TextBox newTextBox = new TextBox();

newTextBox.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(newTextBox_KeyDown);

...

private void newTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Code to do
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert a Canvas object to a textbox.

When the textboxes are created dynamically, you can set a function for the keydown event.

```
mytextbox.KeyDown += myFunction;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are performing the cast (TextBox)sender however sender is not of type TextBox, the "sender" of the event is your Canvas.

Try casting your sender to Canvas and then use FindControl() to find your textbox.

Alternatively you can assign a KeyDown event handler to your TextBox once it has been created.